# check maximum value of tensor in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a custom loss function using keras:

```
import keras.backend as K

def IoU(y_true, y_pred, eps=1e-6):
    if K.max(y_true) == 0.0:
        return IoU(1 - y_true, 1 - y_pred) ## empty image; calc IoU of zeros
    intersection = K.sum(y_true * y_pred, axis=[1,2,3])
    union = K.sum(y_true, axis=[1,2,3]) + K.sum(y_pred, axis=[1,2,3]) - intersection
    return -K.mean((intersection + eps) / (union + eps), axis=0)
```

This results in an endless recursion, since `if K.max(y_true) == 0.0:` always evaluates to true. Why is this the case? Do I need to extract a single value out of the output of `K.max`? I tried converting `y_true` to a numpy array and using `np.max` instead but this was not easily possible.

Or does `1 - y_true` not work the way numpy arrays would work?

Edit: `y_true` and `y_pred` are both tensors with shape:
`Tensor("IoU/Shape:0", shape=(4,), dtype=int32)`. `y_true` is mostly filled with zeros, but some non zero values are present.

Comment: What is the type and content of `y_true` to begin with?

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov I edited the post. However, it is not possible to provide the complete tensor since it is too large.

Comment: Something is wrong here, but I don't know exactly what. You have said `y_pred`, has dtype=int32, but it should not be in int, because of prediction. It should be float32. On the other hand, you have compared it with `0.0` which is float. If it gets convert to int, it may reduce all probabilities to 0 or something like this.

Comment: I did not write the code myself initially so I am not sure why this comparison is done like this. However, I believe the code might have been written with the believe that y_true and y_pred are numpy arrays. I will try changing the comparison to int.